# How do I populate a popup button with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I've found this snippet of code in various place around the 'net:

```
tell window 1
  tell menu of popup button 1
    delete every menu item
    repeat with catListItem in catList
      make new menu item at end of menu items with properties {title:catListItem}
    end repeat
  end tell
end tell
```

When I use it in my AppDelegate script in a Cocoa-AppleScript Application, Xcode gives me an error: *t2t_AppDelegate.applescript:25: error: Expected end of line but found identifier. (-2741)* (Line 25 is "tell menu...")

I'm not sure what I'm missing that would allow me to dynamically populate the popup button with a list of terms (catList) that I'm drawing from another application. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running something earlier than Snow Leopard, It looks like you are using AppleScript Studio terminology (which was deprecated in Snow Leopard).  Using the current **AppleScriptObjC** framework, the user interface items are referenced via outlet properties, for example:

```
property myPopUp : missing value
```

From the Interface Editor, this property is connected to your popup button, which allows you to use it with various methods in the [NSPopupButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and its parents, such as **addItemsWithTitles**.  Once everything is defined and connected, you would use something like:

```
set catList to {"next item", "another item", "Items added"}
myPopUp's addItemsWithTitles_(catList)
```

Comment: Thanks, Red! I've got some catching up to do on the "right" way to do AppleScript now.